# Convert curl into requests

Tags: python, python-requests

How would I convert the following to a requests call?

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer ya29.token" https://play.googleapis.com/v1/accounts/1234/avails/
```

So far I was trying:

```
import requests
headers = { 'Authroization': 'Beader ya29.token' }
url 'https://play.googleapis.com/v1/accounts/1234/avails/'
requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

But this gives me an error. What would be the correct conversion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The above is correct. The problem is a typo:

```
headers = { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ya29.token' }
```

Comment: And the typo is (in case someone was left wondering), the value should read 'Bearer', not 'Beader'